# Site.getName() is null for test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am trying to code a test case for my Apex Class that is used on a Visualforce page.

The problem that I am having is this block of code:

```
String siteName = Site.getName();
if (siteName == 'SiteNameA')
{
    //some logic
}
else if (siteName == 'SiteNameB')
{
    //some other branch of logic
}
```

The problem is that when this controller run in a test class. `Site.getName()` returns a null value. Is there anyway for testing purposes to specify a Site Name? Similar to something like:

`Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('/apex/testPage'));` ?

Comment: Refer this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099qcIAA

Comment: @SantanuBoral Yes I found that, but I see no way possible to do that looking at the runAs documentation. Do you have a Code Snippet or any documentation reference to it?

Comment: There is no site context when running a test. If you provide more information about what you are trying to test then maybe we can provide a better workaround than the response below which is to just ignore the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to test until this method execute in Site context.you need to bypass here. if these don't affect your testing then you can ignore them otherwise add one more condition `Test.isRunningTest()` and Enter in condition.

from official Salesforce document.

```
// registerUser always returns null when the page isn't accessed as a guest user
System.assert(controller.registerUser() == null);
```

[Site Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm)